# Как исправить замерзание формы при её создании не из главного потока

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

В чём суть проблемы: есть статичный класс, который реализует очередь уведомлений, отправленных из главной формы. Из этого класса `AlertThread` следит за потокобезопасной коллекцией `ConcurrentQueue<...> AlertQueue`. При поступлении уведомлений достаём первый в очереди элемент `AlertQueue.TryDequeue(out alert)` и в этом же потоке создаём экземпляр формы `FormAlert` уведомления и показываем пользователю.

Всё по отдельности работает замечательно, как часы, но вот вместе не работает. Создание формы таким образом приводит к тому, что она просто замерзает, хотя поток работает исправно. Когда-то давно пробовал асинхронно вызывать форму, без очереди, и пробовал отдельный event писать, и потом из разных частей кода вызывать, но всегда получал замороженную форму, которая вообще никак не реагировала. Я её даже завершить не мог, только завершение отладки в VS помогало.

Так вот, как это можно исправить? Что мешает форме работать в другом потоке?

Я использую .NET Framework 4.8

Класс Alert:

```
public static class Alert
{
    private static bool IsWork = false;

    private static Thread AlertThread;

    private static ConcurrentQueue<(string, enumType)> AlertQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<(string, enumType)>();

    private static int MaxAlerts;

    public static void Start()
    {
        IsWork = true;

        AlertThread = new Thread(AlertInvoker)
        {
            IsBackground = true,
            Name = "AlertThread BubbleAnimation",
            Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal
        };

        AlertThread.Start();
    }

    public static void Suspend()
    {
        if (AlertThread.IsAlive)
            IsWork = false;
    }

    public static void Resume()
    {
        if (AlertThread.IsAlive)
            IsWork = true;
    }

    private static void AlertInvoker()
    {
        while (IsWork)
        {
            if (AlertQueue.Count < MaxAlerts && AlertQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                (string, enumType) alert;

                if (AlertQueue.TryDequeue(out alert))
                { 
                    FormAlert falert = new FormAlert();
                    falert.showAlert(alert.Item1, alert.Item2, MaxAlerts);
                }
            }

            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }

    public static void AddAlert(string msg, enumType type)
    {
        AlertQueue.Enqueue((msg, type));
        MaxAlerts = (int)Math.Round((Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - 75.0) / 75.0);
    }
}
```

Класс формы уведомления FormAlert:

```
public partial class FormAlert : Form
    {
        public FormAlert()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            buttonClose.Click += (obj, a) => buttonClose_Click(obj, a);
            timer1.Tick += (obj, a) => timer1_Tick(obj, a);
        }

        public enum enumActions
        {
            wait,
            start,
            close
        }

        public enum enumType
        {
            Succsess,
            Warning,
            Error,
            Info
        }

        private FormAlert.enumActions action;

        private int x, y;

        private void buttonClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Interval = 1;
            action = enumActions.close;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (this.action)
            {
                case enumActions.wait:
                    timer1.Interval = 5000;
                    action = enumActions.close;
                    break;
                case enumActions.start:
                    timer1.Interval = 1;
                    if (this.Opacity <= 0.7)
                        this.Opacity += 0.1;
                    if (this.x < this.Location.X)
                    {
                        this.Left--;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (this.Opacity >= 0.7)
                        {
                            action = enumActions.wait;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case enumActions.close:
                    timer1.Interval = 1;
                    this.Opacity -= 0.1;
                    this.Left -= 3;
                    if (base.Opacity <= 0.0)
                    {
                        base.Close();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void showAlert(string msg, enumType type, int m_alert)
        {
            this.Opacity = 0.0;
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            string fname;

            for (int i = 0; i < m_alert - 1; i++)
            {
                fname = "alert" + i.ToString();

                if ((FormAlert)Application.OpenForms[fname] == null)
                {
                    this.Name = fname;
                    this.Text = type.ToString();
                    this.x = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - this.Width + 15;
                    this.y = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - this.Height * i - 75;
                    this.Location = new Point(this.x, this.y);
                    break;
                }

            }
            this.x = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - base.Width;

            switch (type)
            {
                case enumType.Succsess:
                    this.picture.Image = Resources.success_g;
                    break;
                case enumType.Warning:
                    this.picture.Image = Resources.warning_r;
                    break;
                case enumType.Error:
                    this.picture.Image = Resources.error_y;
                    break;
                case enumType.Info:
                    this.picture.Image = Resources.info_b;
                    break;
            }

            if (msg.Length <= 24)
            {
                this.message.Text = msg;
            }
            else if (msg.Length > 24 && msg.Length <= 48)
            {
                this.message.AutoSize = false;
                this.message.MinimumSize = new Size(230, 42);
                this.message.Location = new Point(this.message.Location.X, this.message.Location.Y - 12);
                this.message.Text = msg;
            }
            else if (msg.Length > 48)
            {
                this.message.AutoSize = false;
                this.message.MinimumSize = new Size(230, 63);
                this.message.Location = new Point(this.message.Location.X, this.message.Location.Y - 24);
                this.message.Text = msg;
            }

            this.Show();
            this.action = enumActions.start;
            this.timer1.Interval = 1;
            timer1.Start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @AlexF, так вот в чём дело, понял, спасибо, если хотите, оформите ваш комментарий в виде ответа, я приму его, как верный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формы не работают в потоке без `message loop`, который создается функцией `Application.Run`: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.run?view=netcore-3.1

Стандартное начало программы WinForms:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Эта строчка создает `message loop` для формы. Без него форма мертвая.

Можно попробовать запустить message loop в другом потоке, но это создает много проблем. Пример здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698080/spawn-a-new-thread-to-open-a-new-window-and-close-it-from-a-different-thread

Я рекомендую создавать формы только в главном потоке, а другие задачи делать в рабочих потоках. UI по своей природе однопоточный, его объекты работают с экраном, мышью и клавиатурой, никакого преимущества от потоков в UI нет.